# spring-integration perform ftp from various source

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to download files from various source directory of multiple servers via spring-integration channel adapters.

To be more clear, I have situation 
    Server A Dirs A,B,C,D 
I need to download it in P,Q,R,S dirs on client 
and after successful download remove source dirs.

Is that possible via JAVA DSL or configs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a separate inbound adapter for each directory, or use outbound gateways (separate operations to get - or mget - the files and to rm - remove).

All are supported by the DSL or XML/Java configuration.

Comment: Thanks Sir, will try to implement. I was wondering if a simple demo in your github repoo will be a boon. But thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes; the [ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp) has examples of both techniques.